# C# Multiple Keys to one Value

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, key

I am looking for a C# container that can map multiple keys to a single object. For example: a single person can be referenced by his English name, or his Spanish name. I want to do this so that I don't have to create multiple copies of Dictionaries, and when I add/remove from the structure, I only have to add/remove once. Does such a structure exist?

Comment: How would one add/remove work? A `params[]` overload? In my mind you still have to call `dict.Add()` multiple times, which means @Verarind's solution is the best option.

Comment: Yeah, I actually already considered the multiple keys/multiple Dictionaries solutions, but I have to support over 50 languages! Either way, that means 50 copies of a single person, and I do a lot of adding/removing. It's kind of a waste of space. Wondering if there was a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: @user3685285 _waste of space_? You need to store a key to a pointer. I don't think that there is a structure that needs less space than a dictionary and supports a fast way to access the values.

Comment: @Vera rind, I agree that a Dictionary is the best structure for 1 to many mappings, but I need a many to 1 mapping. Was hoping there'd be a more elegant solution, but it seems I can't get there without building a custom structure with pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it exists: [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

There is no reason why you can't add a single object instance with multiple keys:

```
public class Person
{
    public string EnglishName { get; set; }
    public string SpanishName { get; set; }
}

public static class PersonDictExtensions
{
    public static void AddPerson(this IDictionary<string, Person> persons, Person person)
    {
        persons.Add(person.EnglishName, person);
        persons.Add(person.SpanishName, person);
    }

    public static void RemovePerson(this IDictionary<string, Person> persons, Person person)
    {
        foreach (var item in persons.Where(x => object.ReferenceEquals(x.Value, person)).ToList())
        {
            persons.Remove(item.Key);
        }
    }
}

var person = new Person { EnglishName = "Foo", SpanishName = "Bar" };
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
dict.AddPerson(person);
dict.RemovePerson(person);
```

**EDIT**
Ups I understand: only one add and remove? Hm. Doesn't know that such a structure exists. Maybe you can add an extension method to handle that cases.

I changed the code...